# python scrapy - Output json file empty

Tags: python, wordpress, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and having some problems with the output from my first spider. No matter what I try, the output json file is always empty. Im using the 2.5.1 version due to running into a bug on the current 2.6.1 version. The spiders code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class WormSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'Worm'
allowed_domains = ['parahumans.wordpress.com']
start_urls = ['https://parahumans.wordpress.com/']
custom_settings = {'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 10}
rules = (
    #Rule(
    #   LinkExtractor(allow = r'notebook_Desde_'), follow = True
    #   ),
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow = r'category/stories-arcs-'), follow = True, callback = 'parse_item'
        ),
    )
    
def parse_item(self, response):
yield {
    'Arco': response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/text()').getall(),
    'tags': response.xpath('//span[@class="tag-links"]/text()').getall()
}
```

And the terminal log output when i run scrapy crawl Worm -O Testeo.json :

````
[]
2022-07-03 00:05:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-07-03 00:05:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-07-03 00:05:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-07-03 00:05:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/> (referer: None)
2022-07-03 00:05:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-1-gestation/1-01/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-1-gestation/1-01/#content> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-6-tangle/6-02/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-10/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-08/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-09/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-x-interlude/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-07/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-6-tangle/6-01/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-6-tangle/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (closespider_pagecount)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-05/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-04/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-03/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-06/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-01/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-05/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-07/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-02/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-04/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-06/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-03/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-1-10/arc-5-hive/5-02/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/30-01/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parahumans.wordpress.com/category/stories-arcs-21/arc-30-speck/> (referer: https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)
2022-07-03 00:05:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 9450,
 'downloader/request_count': 25,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 25,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1085925,
 'downloader/response_count': 25,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 25,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 7992,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 4.61569,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_pagecount',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 3, 3, 5, 39, 261991),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 4498394,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 26,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 55934976,
 'memusage/startup': 55934976,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 25,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 25,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 25,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 333,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 333,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 3, 3, 5, 34, 646301)}
2022-07-03 00:05:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (closespider_pagecount)```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are about to your goal. Use `//a//text()` instead of `/text()`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
class WormSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Worm'
    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {'data.json': {'format': 'json'}},
        "FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING": "utf-8"
        } 
    
    allowed_domains = ['parahumans.wordpress.com']
    start_urls = ['https://parahumans.wordpress.com/']
    #custom_settings = {'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 10}
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow = r'category/stories-arcs-'), follow = True, callback = 'parse_item'
            ),
            )
    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'Arco': response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]//a//text()').getall(),
            'tags': response.xpath('//span[@class="tag-links"]//a//text()').getall()
            }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(WormSpider)
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "Arco": ["Gestation 1.1"],
    "tags": ["Emma", "Madison", "Mr. G", "Sophia", "Taylor"]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.9"],
    "tags": [
      "Aegis",
      "Angelica",
      "Bitch",
      "Brutus",
      "Clockblocker",
      "Grue",
      "Judas",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Vista"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.8"],
    "tags": [
      "Angelica",
      "Bitch",
      "Brutus",
      "Grue",
      "Judas",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.7"],
    "tags": [
      "Angelica",
      "Bitch",
      "Brutus",
      "Grue",
      "Judas",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor"
    ]
  },
  { "Arco": ["Agitation 3.5"], "tags": ["Armsmaster", "Taylor"] },
  {
    "Arco": [
      "Interlude 4",
      "Shell 4.11",
      "Shell 4.10",
      "Shell 4.9",
      "Shell 4.8",
      "Shell 4.7",
      "Interlude 3½ (Bonus)",
      "Shell 4.6",
      "Shell 4.5",
      "Shell 4.4"
    ],
    "tags": [
      "Angelica",
      "Bitch",
      "Brutus",
      "Judas",
      "Doctor Q",
      "Grue",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Taylor's Dad",
      "Bakuda",
      "Grue",
      "Taylor",
      "Bakuda",
      "Grue",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Bakuda",
      "Grue",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Bakuda",
      "Grue",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Über",
      "Bakuda",
      "Grue",
      "Leet",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Über",
      "Grue",
      "Leet",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor",
      "Grue",
      "Regent",
      "Tattletale",
      "Taylor"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.4"],
    "tags": ["Armsmaster", "Taylor", "Taylor's Dad"]
  },
  { "Arco": ["Agitation 3.6"], "tags": ["Tattletale", "Taylor"] },
  {
    "Arco": ["Shell 4.1"],
    "tags": ["Emma", "Grue", "Regent", "Tattletale", "Taylor"]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.2"],
    "tags": ["Grue", "Regent", "Tattletale", "Taylor"]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.1"],
    "tags": ["Bitch", "Grue", "Mrs. Knott", "Sophia", "Taylor"]
  },
  {
    "Arco": ["Agitation 3.3"],
    "tags": ["Angelica", "Bitch", "Grue", "Regent", "Tattletale", "Taylor"]
```

... so on

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your code and I get the exact same result, an empty json file. Which is weird, because your result is exactly what I would expect to get with a working code, so the problem must be somewhere else, any ideas? In case it is relevant, my USER-AGENT configuration is : Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148

Comment: @Nicolas Blanco, I'm always getting json Output

Comment: Just run the code

Comment: I copied your code exactly and tried running it both as a scrapy spider and as a python file(python Worm.py), in both cases the resulting json file is empty. I'm starting to think the problem is not in the code per se but somewhere else?

Comment: I finally got it working, turns out my def parse_item was outside of the class spider, which I thought was the way this is done, but apparently isn't. I only realized it after comparing both codes a dozen times and when I copied your code, I wrote it the wrong way again which is way it wasnt working. Thanks a lot, with this I now consider the question answered